# How to store lower 32 bits in a SMLAWy instruction?

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I want to use `SMLAWy` instruction to store the lower 32 bits into the destination register. However, the documentation says that `SMLAWy` instruction stores the upper 32 bits of the 48-bit result into the destination register. How can I do this?
[Here is the link to the ARM documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0231b/CIHJFEII.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single instruction which does what you want, but the neatest solution would probably be a combination of `sxth` and `mla`, i.e. extract the relevant 16-bit operand into a temporary register so you can then do a plain 32x32 multiply and accumulate the bottom 32 bits.

Comment: That is one possible solution but that increases the number of instructions required to perform the whole operation. Is there some other way to do it instead of using `MLA` instruction?

Comment: Since there is no instruction implementing a 32x16 multiply from a packed halfword operand and accumulating the _lower_ 32 bits, no. The only operations returning the least-significant part of a multiplication result are `mul` and `mla`, and they are 32x32 operations. However, if you have anywhere _else_ in the algorithm which also requires unpacking the 16-bit data for other reasons, it might be worth trying to reorder things so you can take advantage of that for the multiply as well.